# How to use G Power 3 to calculate statistical power in mixed design ANOVA with unequal group sample sizes

Tags: repeated-measures, sample-size, statistical-power

In G power 3, ANOVA repeated measures within-between interaction: Only the total sample size is reported assuming equal sample size for the two groups.

My questions are:

1. How would it work if the sample sizes are slightly different, for example: N1/ N2 = 1.16.
2. I have to input correlation between repeated measures. Is this the correlation between repeats after merging the data from the two groups?
3. Information about non-centrality parameter would be helpful.

Comment: I don't know why this hasn't been answered yet. My only two suggestions are to take out the g-power bit. It seems like your questions are basically unrelated to that software and it may discourage somebody who is familiar with power analysis and not g-power. Second, it may help to break your questions into two or three separate questions. Just a thought. Good luck.

Comment: @IVM 1. the convention in power calculations is to use the minimum of either sample size as the $n$ of both samples. Doing otherwise is usually not analytically tractable but can be done anyway with simulation. 2: No, the correlation is among repeated measures within individual subject to the same experimental condition (in case this is a crossover design). 3: The NCP is usually not helpful, but if you went about performing a simulation it can be estimated using method of moments. Does this start to answer your question?